# Do we have to add '%%context_value%%' field in Scenarios in Web Recommendations that is in Personalization Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

When I add Scenarios in Web Recommendations, most Scenarios (like Bought-Bought, Click-Bought) have a this '%%context_value%%' string that appears in the Scenario Statement. 
Do I have to enter any Attribute/Field value from my Catalog here?
If yes then what is the Attribute/Field to be entered.
Is this is automatically applied based on the context of the Webpage where it is used?
If yes then how exactly will that happen, If you wouldn't mind explaining with example. What value will this pick if it is on a webpage with many products?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context value takes information from the current page that is correct but not like you might think. I really is based on your implementation of the recommendation call to salesforce.

You implement the code on a page like [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_customize_the_calls.htm&type=5). All these values should be dynamic and filled with values in  the current context.

The scenarios you have shown need the category parameter. The following code could be used if you have a category "shoes" in your product catalog and this value would also need to be filled dynamicly by the website when the user visits the category "shoes". Or any page where this szenario should be shown.

```
https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/MID/category/recommend.json?category=shoes
```

If you would have different scenarios like "bought bought" or "view viewed" then the recommendation calls would need a different parameter which is "item". The item parameter must then point either to your productcode or sku-parameter of your productcatalog (depending on your implementation). Therefore the recommendation call for the product page of product 12345 would be:

```
https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/MID/category/recommend.json?item=12345
```

Just try to fill most of the parameters that can be filled and leave out those where you not have any information. For user: happy@new-year.com [can also be a number, but has some sideeffects] on the product 12345 which is from the shoes category it could be this.

```
https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/MID/category/recommend.json?item=12345&category=shoes&email=happy@new-year.com
```

Resource:

- [**Customize Recommendation Call**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_pb_customize_the_calls.htm&type=5)